# Stability Analysis Finite Difference Methods Black-Scholes PDE

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, heat-equation, finite-differences, parabolic-pde

$\mathbf{Background}$

Let $u = u(x,t)$ be the solution of the following forward parabolic initial
boundary-value problem in one space dimension,
$$u_t - a u_{xx} = f(x,t) \text { for } 0 < x < L \text { and } 0 < t <T,$$

with the boundary conditions
\begin{align*}
u &= \gamma_0(t) \text { at } x = 0, \text { for } 0 < t < T,\\
u &= \gamma_L(t) \text { at } x = L, \text { for } 0 < t < T,
\end{align*}
and the initial condition
$$u = u_0(x) \text { for } \text { at } t = 0, \text { for } 0 < x < L.$$

The problem is a model of heat conduction in one space dimension and $a > 0$ is the thermal conductivity.

Define a finite difference grid on the rectangle $[0,L] \times [0,T],$
$$(x_p,t_n) = (p\Delta x,n\Delta t) \text { for } 0 \leq p \leq P \text { and } 0 \leq n \leq N , \text { with } \Delta x = \frac{L}{P}, \text { and } \Delta t = \frac{T}{N}.$$

Suppose $U_p^{n} \approx u(x_p,t_n),\, f_p^{n} = f(x_p,t_n),\, \gamma_0^n = \gamma_0(t_n),\, \gamma_L^n = \gamma_L(t_n) \text { and } u_{0p} = u_0(x_p).$

Put $\rho = a\Delta t / \Delta x^2.$
The explicit Euler method for the problem is:
\begin{equation}
U_p^{n+1} = f_p^n\Delta t + \rho U_{p-1}^n + (1-2\rho)U_p^n + \rho U_{p+1}^n \text { for } 1 \leq p \leq P-1 \text { and } 0 \leq n \leq N-1.
\end{equation}

If $\rho \leq 1/2,$ or equivalently if $2a\Delta t \leq \Delta x^2,$ then the explicit Euler method is stable:
\begin{multline}
\label{stability theorem explicit}
|| \mathbf{U}_{0:P}^n ||_{\infty} \leq 
\max \big\{||(\mathbf{u_0})_{1:P-1}||_{\infty}, ||\gamma_0^{0:n}||_\infty, ||\gamma_L^{0:n} ||_\infty \big\} + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}|| \mathbf{f}_{1:P-1}^{j}  ||_\infty \Delta t \,\,
\text { for } 0 \leq n \leq N.
\end{multline}

$\mathbf{My\,\,Question}$

I'm computing numerical solution of Black-Scholes PDE using explicit Euler method. I want to undertake stability analysis similar to what I have indicated for the numerical solution of heat equation using explicit Euler. We know that explicit Euler is conditionally stable. However, unlike heat equation, for Black-Scholes PDE, I can't find relevant literature that derives bounds on the discretization steps. I have been reading some textbooks that simply say that $\Delta t /\Delta x^2$ should be below a certain threshold but do not indicate that threshold explicitly.

Could someone suggest useful references (journal articles/books/research papers) that undertake stability analysis of this kind for computing numerical solution to Black-Scholes PDE using finite difference methods (explicit/implicit/Crank-Nicolson)?

Comment: It seems your best bet would be to deal with the ``constant coefficient'' form. Page 6 of <http://people.math.gatech.edu/~meyer/MA6635/chap4.pdf> shows a change of variable  $y = \log S / K$ and function redefinition $P$ that reduce the partial differential equation to $P_t + (\sigma^2/2)P_{yy} + (r - \sigma^2/2)P_y - rP = 0$ which is your heat conduction equation, for which you have a stability analysis already. Now it's a matter of translating the $\Delta t / (\Delta x)^2$ condition to $\Delta t / (\Delta y)^2$.

Comment: So maybe something like $\Delta t / (\Delta S)^2 \leq (\sigma KS)^{-2}$?

Comment: @A rural reader very useful reference. Thanks for that. Do you mind elaborating how you got this bound ?

Comment: I will, below. I think the change of variable is actually $y = \log(S/K)$ so that'll change things a little, but not materially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation above is to make the change of variable $y := \log(S/K)$ and the function redefinition referenced in the notes. Those two let you transform
the original problem
$$V_t(t, S) + (\sigma^2/2)S^2 V_{SS}(t, S) + rSV_S(t, S) - rV(t, S) = 0,$$
with appropriate initial condition, e.g. $V(0, S) = \phi(S)$, into the equivalent system
$$P_t(t, y) + (\sigma^2/2)P_{yy}(t, y) + (r - \sigma^2/2)P_y(t, y) - rP(t, y) = 0$$
with initial condition $P(0, y) = \gamma(y)$.

I point this out because you already have a stability analysis for the latter, and if you have stably generated *its* solution you'll likewise have the solution for the former. You know from your stability analysis that the explicit scheme needs $(\sigma^2/2)\Delta t / (\Delta y)^2 \leq 1/2$, that is
$$ \sigma^2 \Delta t / (\Delta y)^2 \leq 1.$$
With $y = \log(S/K)$ I simply computed the differential $\Delta y = (1/S)\Delta S$ and substituted to get
$$ \sigma^2 S^2 \Delta t / (\Delta S)^2 \leq 1.$$
In practice this might mean the explicit scheme for the standard Black-Scholes system requires dynamic step-sizing.

Comment: After making necessary transformations , Black-Scholes system reduces to $u_{\tau}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2 u_{yy}$ where I have made the substitution $\tau = (T - t).$ This is now our heat equation and we can use stability analysis. So, instead of $\Delta t$, I think it should be $\Delta \tau$ in the final answer . Moreover if we see page 13 of the notes (fourth line from last), we have $u_{t}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2 u_{yy}$. I think this $t$ represents $\tau$  because otherwise it should be $u_{t}= - \frac{1}{2}\sigma ^2 u_{yy}$ as on line 2 of page 7 where we have initial condition as $u(y,T)$.

Comment: @A rural reader Hi, I will be very grateful if you can have a look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3996241/715112 .It is based on the notes that you mentioned in your answer to this question.