# Proof involving tridiagonal diagonally dominant matrix

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics, finite-differences, tridiagonal-matrices

$\mathbf{Background}$

Define a finite difference grid on the rectangle $[0,X] \times [0,T]$,

$(x_j,t_n) = (x_0 + j\Delta x,n\Delta t) \text { for } 0 \leq j \leq M \text { and } 0 \leq n \leq N , \text { with } \Delta x = \frac{X - x_0}{M}, \text { and } \Delta t = \frac{T}{N}.$

After some manipulations, we obtain

$ A_{j,j-1}U_{j-1}^n + A_{j,j}U_{j}^n + A_{j,j+1}U_{j+1}^{n} = - U_j^{n+1}.$

To be specific, let $U^n$ be the vector $U^n = (u_1^n,\ldots,u_{M-1}^n)$ then the system to be solved is
$$AU^n = b^n $$

where $A$ is the $(M-1) \times (M-1)$ tridiagonal matrix with entries

$$A_{j,j-1} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 x_j^2 \frac{1}{\Delta x^2} - rx_j \frac{1}{2 \Delta x}$$
$$A_{j,j} =  -\sigma^2 x_j^2 \frac{1}{\Delta x^2} - r - \frac{1}{\Delta t} $$
$$A_{j,j-1} = \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 x_j^2 \frac{1}{\Delta x^2} + rx_j \frac{1}{2 \Delta x}$$
$\text { for } j = 1,\ldots,M-1.$ Here $r > 0.$

Let $b_j^n = -\frac{1}{\Delta t}u_j^{n+1}.$

Assume that the boundary data $u_0^n$ and $u_M^n$ are non-negative. Also assume that the initial data $u_j^N$ is non-negative. Furthermore, assume that $A_{j,j-1} \geq 0$ for all $j \geq 1.$ Then it follows by inspection that $|A_{jj}| > A_{j,j-1} + A_{j,j+1}$ for all $j \geq 1.$ So, $A$ is diagonally dominant and hence invertible.  Hence the values $\{u_j^n\}$ can be computed.

$\mathbf{Question}$

Suppose that at some interior mesh point $(x_k,t_p)$ with $0 < k < M, 0 \leq p < N$ the value $u_k^p$ is bigger than all the other values, i.e.
$$u_k ^ p \geq u_j^n \,\,\text { for all } j , n.$$ Since the initial and boundary data are non-negative, we have $u_k^p \geq 0.$ I want to show that this is not possible i.e. there cannot be a value $u_k^p$ which exceeds the maximum value of $u$ at $x_0$, at $x_M = X$ ot $t_n = T.$

In fact, the working has already been shown in the following notes: [https://people.math.gatech.edu/~meyer/MA6635/chap4.pdf](https://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Emeyer/MA6635/chap4.pdf)  $\,\,\mathbf {page 16}$ but I'm not being able to understand it.

I understand that $$A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_k^p + A_{k,k+1}u_k^{p} = - r u_k^p - \frac{1}{\Delta t}u_k^p < -\frac{1}{\Delta t}u_k^{p+1}.$$ But I don't understand how $$A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_{k-1}^p + A_{k,k+1}u_{k+1}^{p}  \geq A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_k^p + A_{k,k+1}u_k^{p}$$ and why is there inconsistency with the $k$th equation of $AU^p = b^p?$

$\mathbf{Edit}$

I think there is a mistake in the text on page 16. It should be $$A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_{k-1}^p + A_{k,k+1}u_{k+1}^{p}  \leq A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_k^p + A_{k,k+1}u_k^{p}$$ and since , $$A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_k^p + A_{k,k+1}u_k^{p} <  -\frac{1}{\Delta t}u_k^{p+1}$$ there is inconsistency with the $k$th equation because $$A_{kk}u_k^p + A_{k,k-1}u_{k-1}^p + A_{k,k+1}u_{k+1}^{p} = -\frac{1}{\Delta t}u_k^{p+1}. $$

Comment: It would be helpful to explicitly include the specific parabolic PDE that you are solving. You notation suggests that you are either using an explicit method or stepping backwards in time. I believe that your intention is to move forwards in time using the implicit Euler method?

Comment: I'm trying to undertake stability analysis for Black-Scholes PDE computing numerical solution using implicit Euler method where the initial condition is given at $t = T$ and not $t = 0.$ So time step is backwards.